# Minecraft Server In Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, minecraft

again. I have issues while trying to launch a Minecraft server. Not the server itself, but I can't let other people join. I, myself can only connect with "localhost." I can't connect with my external I.P. address. Can anyone point me in the right direction to allow connecting to my server from my external I.P?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why "Hello" isn't showing...

Answer (score 1):

When your friends try and login your router doesn't know where to direct the traffic so it just sends back a no response. To fix this you need to forward the port number used by your Minecraft server to your computers internal ip address.

Open your router home page (can usually be accessed by entering 192.168.0.1 into your browsers address bar) then look for port forwarding. On the port forwarding page enter the port number used by your server into the start/end port boxes and your internal ip address into the ip address box.

As an example I would have to enter 25565 as the port and 192.168.0.5 as the ip address.

If you need to find your routers gateway address (to access the home page) enter the command *ip route show* and look for the default via which is your routers ip address. Alternatively the src address is your computers internal ip address if you needed to find that as well.

> default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
>   192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.5  metric 9

I apologise for being a little bit vague as every router is different and the same approach may not work for all router models but in theory it should be very similar.

Comment: Thank you I will have to try this later. ^^ If it works, I'll accept this answer.